# NIO: How to avoid socketChannel.read(buffer) if no data available in buffer

Tags: java, nio

I want to write one NIO Server\Client application where I want Server to read the socketChannel only if data is available in the Channel. In my demo App for testing purpose Client just connect to server but never sends the request to server, But I found that **selectionKey.isReadable()** always returns true. I expect since client is never sending request **isReadalble()** should return false.
Problem that I face with **isReadable=true** is it makes my application to try reading data from socketChannel which I really want to avoid.
Is there any way by which my server can be notified when there is data to read in socket channel? 
Following is read() method in my server App where isReadable() always returns true:

```
private void read(SelectionKey selectionKey){    
    if(selectionKey.isReadable()){     
        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel)selectionKey.channel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(256);
        try {
            socketChannel.read(buffer);
            String value = new String(buffer.array()).trim();
            System.out.println("Value is: " +value);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Not able to read");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to write one NIO Server\Client application where I want Server to read the socketChannel only if data is available in the Channel.

That's what `Selector` and `OP_READ` are for.

> In my demo App for testing purpose Client just connect to server but never sends the request to server, But I found that `selectionKey.isReadable()` always returns true.

So it's readable.

> I expect since client is never sending request `isReadable()` should return false.

Wrong. It also returns true if the peer has closed the connection. So, if there is no data and the channel is readable, the peer must be closing the connection. You are ignoring the return value of `read()`, so you never find out, so you never close the channel, so it remains readable.

```
socketChannel.read(buffer);
String value = new String(buffer.array()).trim();
```

This should be:

```
int count = socketChannel.read(buffer);
if (count == -1)
{
    socketChannel.close();
    return;
}
String value = new String(buffer.array(), 0, buffer.limit());
```

There should be no need for calling `trim()` on your own protocol. If you don't want spaces, don't send them.